# Asyncio: Create One Event Loop Per Child Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

### Context

I'm using Python [Playwright's](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python) asynchronous API to test a web application. I want to run two batches of coroutines in two child threads concurrently where each thread will have its own event loop.

### A Simple MRE

Consider the following program:

```py
import asyncio
import threading


async def func_1(thread_name):
    print(f"Coroutine from batch 1 in {thread_name}")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


async def func_2(thread_name):
    print(f"Coroutine from batch 2 in {thread_name}")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


async def batch_1(thread_name):
    """Runs three func_1 coroutines concurrently."""
    await asyncio.gather(*[func_1(thread_name) for _ in range(3)])


async def batch_2(thread_name):
    """Runs three func_2 coroutines concurrently."""
    await asyncio.gather(*[func_2(thread_name) for _ in range(3)])


def main():

    thread_pool = []
    for cnt, batch in enumerate((batch_1, batch_2), start=1):
        thread_name = f"thread_{cnt}"
        t = threading.Thread(
            target=asyncio.run, args=(batch(thread_name),), name=thread_name
        )
        t.start()
        thread_pool.append(t)

    for t in thread_pool:
        t.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here I ran three `func_1`s in `batch_1` concurrently via `asyncio.gather`. I did the same with `func_2` in `batch_2`. Then I ran `batch_1` and `batch_2` coroutine functions in two different threads. Each child thread has its own event loop created via `asyncio.run`. The program prints out the following:

```
Coroutine from batch 1 in thread_1
Coroutine from batch 2 in thread_2
Coroutine from batch 1 in thread_1
Coroutine from batch 2 in thread_2
Coroutine from batch 1 in thread_1
Coroutine from batch 2 in thread_2
```

### Question

From the out-of-sequence output above, it's clear that the threads are running concurrently. However—

- How is this working? Does it create two different event-loops where each of them only executes the tasks scheduled on it, while the threads pre-emptively decide which event-loop should get its turn?
- For my real use case, this seems to work like a champ. However, I'd like to know if this is a "correct" approach?

Comment: Each call to `asyncio.run` will create a new event loop. Is there a reason you’re using threads here, though?

Comment: Yes, I was experiencing a considerable amount of slow down on my primary event loop once the number of test coroutines reached over 250. I tested multiple times to make sure I wasn't running any blocking code there. The event loop still has to loop through the tasks sequentially to execute them. Putting a new batch on a new thread worked like a champ but I was skeptical if this is an anti-pattern.

Comment: 250 seems like a pretty low number of tasks to stress your application. I suspect the problem has more to do with what they’re doing than the number of tasks.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the individual tasks are pretty heavy. They open a headless chrome instance and travel to different pages of a web application and test them out sequentially. After splitting the tasks by half, with 125 tasks on each batch and running them from two different threads I got like a 30 second speed boost (thread spawning overhead I guess).  The total runtime was around 6 minutes for 250 tasks.

Comment: how are you controlling Chrome? Are you using a library that’s blocking the event loop?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft's Playwright Python's async API. Playwright supports asyncio natively, so I double that's the case.

Comment: To answer your second question, no, it's not the "correct" approach, a single event loop is able to scale to much larger number of tasks than 250. This approach is probably just hiding a flaw in some of your tasks, which will come back to bite you. I believe asyncio has a debug mode that you can use to tell you which tasks are blocking, so that you can move just _those_ parts to `run_in_executor` or equivalent.

Comment: Yes. Understood. That's what I needed to hear. Thanks.